# Chat room app on Android without openfire

Tags: php, android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I plan to use asmack lib for a chatroom app on android, however, I just want to use PHP as server scripts with mysql as backend database server. I hope I can find a way to build it without openfire, is it possible? Any suggestions to implement them?

Comment: So you are basically asking for a XMPP server in PHP and none of the tags (android, openfire, asmack) is related to the question? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault, I should add PHP here. I searched XMPP server in PHP, find there is an ongoing project hosted on http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/, hope some guys can share their experience using it!

Comment: xmpphp is a XMPP **client** library, not an server. I suggest that you rephrase the question, but it will get eventually closed. If you couldn't google an XMPP PHP server, there is likely none. Have also a look here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/ Why has it to be an server in PHP, there are many alternatives, which have a good API  that you could use via PHP.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Flow, you are absolutely right! What makes me looking for a PHP Xmpp server is I have a VPS, I want to play with instant message, the server has limited space and memory. Thus, I hope I can cut the middle ware as few as possible. Since it has already had PHP, I am looking for a PHP xmpp server. Do you think openfire has a php api? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever server you want.  asmack is a client library that communicates via XMPP, which is language agnostic.  Select any server you would like and your client should work fine.

Your comments about whether OpenFire has a PHP api though are somewhat confusing, do you want an OpenFire server or not?  The language the server is written in is irrelevant to your client app.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, yes, you are right. I can choose the language I like to access XMPP server. My last comment is about if there is a client library written in PHP to access Openfire server. Maybe, I should try xmpphp. Anyway, thank for your answering!